# How to encrypt or hide "value" in option in Select Tag (HTML) - MVC 5

Tags: javascript, html, encryption, asp.net-mvc-5

I am sending the User list from controller to View.

My Action:

```
public ActionResult Users()
    {
        ViewBag.UserList = new SelectList(db.Users.ToList(), "Id", "UserName");
        return View();
    }
```

I am populaing the dropdown with the following:

```
 @Html.DropDownList("Users", (SelectList)ViewBag.UserList, "Select Users", new { @class = "required form-control" })
```

When I Open developer tool in chrome I see the Option Value Like this:

```
<select class="required form-control" id="User_UserRole" name="Users" type="hidden">
<option value="">Select User</option>
<option value="3aeca037-99d1-4cb2-a08c-6a5a3427f35c">admin</option>
<option value="3df4ebc6-f7ee-44b9-9f0b-2083e5921aac">superadmin</option>
</select>
```

How to enrypt or hide this option value

 "value="3aeca037-99d1-4cb2-a08c-6a5a3427f35c" 
in select tag, so its safe to use. Please help!

Comment: Why in the world would you want to do that. And what make you think it has anything to do with security or being _safe to use_ (and its already a meaningless `Guid` anyway)

Comment: Unless he build some dictionary/link to the Guid on the server side that he can re-link to during a post-back.

Comment: As other users had commented, it is not going to provide extra security, because whatever you render on values will be understood by your code so you are just changing the display of value but it's internal value remains same, However if you still want to achieve this you can use tagbuilder  and use custom attribute to encrypt and decrypt values, I am not sure how it will pump up security, If you have a use case please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing that happens in the browser can be considered safe or hidden.

What you want simply isn't possible.

Any security-sensitive operations need to happen on the server. If you want to let the user choose between "admin" and "superadmin", just give them those options in the dropdown, then when they submit the form, use server-side code to decide what if anything, you want to do.

If you don't want them to see one or more of the options, do not generate the `<option>` tag for the items you don't want to show.

Also, make sure you don't allow invalid options on the server side based on user input. For example, if you only want to allow "admin" make sure that if they manually create a "superadmin" option and submit it, that you reject this on the server side.

Nothing that comes in from the outside world can be trusted.

Answer (score -1):

By doing this you can hide the option value

```
<option value="k" style="display:none;">kumar</option>
```

Comment: That hides the `<option>` itself (which is rather pointless), not the `value` (which cannot be done unless it omitted - which would also make it pointless)

Comment: Thank you shankar for your comment but @StephenMuecke is right as I don't want to reveal the `value` in `option` which I think is not possible!